# How do I know my input is being sanitized by express-validator?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sanitization, express-validator

I've implemented `express-validator` and am trying to sanitize an input field where users are searching a particular query.

The test query I'm using is `<script>Malicious code</script`. As the request comes in, I use:

```
req.sanitizeQuery('searchQuery');
```

When I then check to see if the query has been sanitized, the string hasn't been altered/sanitized in any way.

I could be fundamentally misunderstanding sanitization here, in which case please point it out. If I am, then I can go and fill in my gaps on knowledge, but in the meantime, what "test" query can I throw at my sanitizer to check that it's working?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at the documentation, [express-validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-validator) is meant to be used as middleware.

So I would say you want some code that looks a bit like this:

```
const { validationResult } = require('express-validator/check');
const { sanitizeQuery } = require('express-validator/filter');

// Setup the request handler, give it some validation middleware
// then the main request handler
app.get('/search', [sanitizeQuery('searchQuery').escape()], function(req, res, next) {
  // Deal with any errors
  const errors = validationResult(req);
  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    return res.status(422).json({ errors: errors.mapped() });
  }

  // req.query.searchQuery was sanitised via the middleware, it should now
  // be clean.
  console.log(req.query.searchQuery);
});
```

We're using the sanitizeQuery function as middleware which is going to sanitise the value `req.query.searchQuery`. I'm assuming since it's a sanitisation function, it will not trigger any errors coming from validationResult, instead it will return a clean response for you.

You should then be able to request your service at your `{{host}}/search?searchQuery= <script>Malicious code</script>` where `{{host}}` is your services host such as `http://localhost:8080`.

Comment: But `sanitizeQuery('searchQuery')` doesn't actually sanitize anything... the query remains the same. You have to `sanitizeQuery('searchQuery').escape()` for it to actually sanitize, right?

Comment: `sanitizeQuery` returns a sanitisation chain which you can then be chained onto as you showed. However the function `escape()` does not appear in the docs I linked above, I can only assume that the `escape` function does not exist and you'll have to use `customSanitizer` to create a custom sanitiser to suit your needs here.

Comment: Ah as you said, `escape` is valid, it is shown in the validator.js docs which are used for the sanitiser - https://github.com/chriso/validator.js so yes that would be the correct syntax I believe.